# Temporaily disabling the C# Rich Edit undo buffer while performing syntax highlighting

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rich-text-editor, richedit

I already have a pretty decent [syntax highlighter](http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/images/projects/binaryfileschemagui.png) in my Rich Edit control but I have one final problem before it is fully useful:
Whenever I run the syntax coloring it records those coloring actions in the undo buffer, which I do not really want. Is there any way to temporarily disable recording undo actions so that after a coloring the user can press undo and it will just undo the user's own actions and not the automated syntax highlighter?

I don't think I have the time to implement the Scintilla.NET editor just to get around this problem though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to handle undo/redo yourself instead of relying on RTB, which means hooking into the keyboard events to listen for CTRL+Z, etc.

You can see how this author from codeproject did it for a similar RTB-overridden syntax highlighting editor:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/SyntaxHighlighting.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Almost as @Karl Edwall says above, but not quite: Use `EM_GETOLEINTERFACE` to obtain `IRichEditOle` interface and query it for `IID_ITextDocument`.

Once you get that, use (instead of Freeze/Unfreeze from the other answer) the `Undo()` method:

- `Undo(tomSuspend,NULL);` to suspend undo temporarily
- `Undo(tomResume,NULL);` to resume it again

(See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199852.)
It requires RichEdit 3.0, but that’s shipping since Windows XP SP1.